# Groupby year and calculate the average and count the size in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Contract_ID    Place         Contract_Date      Price
1              Bangalore     2018-10-25         100
2              Bangalore     2018-08-25         200
3              Bangalore     2019-10-25         300
4              Bangalore     2019-11-25         200
5              Bangalore     2019-10-25         400
6              Chennai       2018-10-25         100
7              Chennai       2018-10-25         200
8              Chennai       2018-10-25         100
9              Chennai       2018-10-25         300
10             Chennai       2019-10-25         400
11             Chennai       2019-10-25         600
```

From the above I would like to generate below table using pandas.

Expected Output:

```
Place       Year     Number_of_Contracts    Average_Price   
Bangalore   2018     2                      150
Bangalore   2019     3                      300
Chennai     2018     4                      175
Chennai     2019     2                      500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with years created by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and tuples for new columns names:

```
df['Contract_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract_Date'])
df1 = (df.groupby(['Place', df['Contract_Date'].dt.year.rename('Year')])['Price']
         .agg([('Number_of_Contracts','size'),('Average_Price','mean')])
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
       Place  Year  Number_of_Contracts  Average_Price
0  Bangalore  2018                    2            150
1  Bangalore  2019                    3            300
2    Chennai  2018                    4            175
3    Chennai  2019                    2            500
```

Solution [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=namedagg#named-aggregation), but is necessary pandas 0.25+:

```
df['Contract_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract_Date'])
df1 = (df.groupby(['Place', df['Contract_Date'].dt.year.rename('Year')])
         .agg(Number_of_Contracts=('Contract_ID','size'),
              Average_Price=('Price','mean'))
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
       Place  Year  Number_of_Contracts  Average_Price
0  Bangalore  2018                    2            150
1  Bangalore  2019                    3            300
2    Chennai  2018                    4            175
3    Chennai  2019                    2            500
```